# What's wrong with this command in SQL plus?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, sqlplus

I want to count the number of employees

```
SQL> select count(ename) AS number of people, from emp;
select count(ename) AS number of people, from emp
                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected


SQL>
```

Here's my table

```
 SQL> select ename from emp;

 ENAME
 ----------
 KING
 BLAKE
 CLARK
 JONES
 MARTIN
 ALLEN
 TURNER
 JAMES
 WARD
 FORD
 SMITH

 ENAME
 ----------
 SCOTT
 ADAMS
 MILLER

 14 rows selected.

 SQL>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma after the "people" is probably what's causing the error.

You will also need to use a different alias for the count() column, either by removing the spaces or replacing them with underscores.

Comment: Or using double quotes: `as "Number Of People"`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma before the FROM clause. Also, you can't have spaces in field name, use underscores instead.

Also, it's good practice to capitalise keywords:

```
SELECT COUNT(ename) AS number_of_people FROM emp
```